# how to convert  a php Script to c#

Tags: c#, php

```
<?php

$list = array(
    array(
        'id' => '1',
        'pid' => '2',
        'value' => 'Value Foo 1',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '2',
        'pid' => '6',
        'value' => 'Value Foo 2',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '3',
        'pid' => '5',
        'value' => 'Value Foo 3',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '4',
        'pid' => '2',
        'value' => 'Value Foo 4',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '5',
        'pid' => '0',
        'value' => 'Value Foo 5',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '6',
        'pid' => '0',
        'value' => 'Value Foo 6',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '7',
        'pid' => '6',
        'value' => 'Value Foo 7',
    ),
    array(
       'id' => '8',
       'pid' => '2',
       'value' => 'Value Foo 8',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '9',
        'pid' => '5',
        'value' => 'Value Foo 9',
    ),
);

//
// Creating a lookup array
//
$lookup = array();
foreach( $list as $item )
{
    $item['children'] = array();
    $lookup[$item['id']] = $item;
}

//
// Now build tree.
//
$tree = array();
foreach( $lookup as $id => $foo )
{
    $item = &$lookup[$id];
    if( $item['pid'] == 0 )
    {
        $tree[$id] = &$item;
    }
    else if(isset($lookup[$item['pid']]))
    {
        $lookup[$item['pid']]['children'][$id] = &$item;
    }
    else
    {
        $tree['_orphans_'][$id] = &$item;
    }
}

print_r( $tree );
?>
```

This is what i Have in c#

```
    public class Thing { 
             public String _id; 
             public int Bar; 
             public string _pid; 
    }
          var items = new[] {
                 new Thing { _id = "item1", _pid = "root", Baz = "a" },
                 new Thing {_id = "item2", _pid = "item1", Baz= "b" },
                 new Thing { _id = "item3", _pid = "item1", Baz = "c" },
                 new Thing { _id = "item4", _pid = "item1", Baz = "d" },
                 new Thing { _id = "item5", _pid = "item1", Baz = "e" },
                 new Thing { _id = "item6", _pid = "item1", Baz = "f" }
              };
//Then I create a lookup 
ILookup<string, Thing> lookup = items.ToLookup(i => i._id); 

//here is when I want to create a condition for each item in lookup to search if the _pid is in //the lookup as an item _id

foreach (IGrouping<string, Thing> item in lookup){ 

//here I dont know how to add a children object to the parent item and add a reference to the //current item 
//this is how Iam doing in php 
if(isset($lookup[$item['_pid']])) { 
$lookup[$item['_pid']]['children'][_id] = &$item; //<-item is passed by reference 
}
```

Thanks..
Regards

Comment: Needs way more context. What are you doing in PHP, and what are you doing in C#? What do the codes have to do with each other?

Comment: So you actually want to convert PHP code to C# and not "pass a PHP function to C#" (whatever that means)?

Comment: This question does not make a whole lot of sense. Are you trying to **rewrite** this procedure in C# and having trouble with it, or are you trying to execute a PHP script and then use the **results** in a separate C# program?

Comment: He seems to be building a recursive tree, and i think he needs to pass the data by reference so that it acts in as a tree like structure.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use real objects than anonymous objects for this unless you know what you're doing!

Comment: Still a little vague on what you're after but I'd dump the ILookup and just hold an IList of the objects and look at using methods such as Where to lookup the things you want.